# how to get the order of certain items with jquery sortable("toArray")

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-sortable, sortables

In this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ga89T/10/

I have 3 Sections (section 1, section 3 and section 3). In this example you can try, when I sort the sections, the function sortable("toArray") returns the order of those sections.

Now I would like to get the order of such sections with `class="current"`.

I tried the following:

```
$("#accordion.current").sortable("toArray");
```

but it returns `[object object]`

How can I select certain sections to be sorted?

Comment: Returns correct sort order (like `acc3,acc2,acc1`) for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use the descendant operator because the sortable itself doesn't have a `.current` class. Second, you may be better off using the `.map` function: http://jsfiddle.net/ga89T/12/.

```
var order = $("#accordion .current").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

Comment: Hmm, another Point. Suppose I have the following order (acc2 acc1). After I saved the sections in database, I would like the sections to be sorted in this order when I call the the sections from database. Is it possible to pass jquery.sortable() this list (acc2 acc1) , so that the sections  are sorted in this order?